# In SASS how do you return a list from a function?

Tags: sass

I am working on an angular library and am trying to create a function that takes a color pallet and a name and returns a list so I can create CSS variables. Any help or ideas is appreciated!

```
$violets-palette: (
100: #e1cced,
200: #9064b3,
300: #6a408a,
400: #5d357e,
500: $violet,
600: #311a52,
700: #2d054c,
800: #28053d,
900: #1f0532
);

$reds-palette: (
50: #fee9e8,
100: #fbc8c6,
200: #f9a4a1,
300: #f77f7b,
400: #f5635e,
500: $precise-red,
600: #f1413c,
700: #ef3833,
800: #ed302b,
900: #ea211d
);

@function createVariables($palette, $name){
  @each $key, $value in $palette {
    @if $key != 'contrast' {
      @if $key == 500 {
        @return '--' + $name  + ':' +  #{$value};
      } @else {
        @return #{'--' + $name + '-' + $key}   + ':' + #{$value};
      }
    } 
  }
}


:root{
  //This would loop over the returned list
  createVariables($reds-palette, 'precise-red');
}
```

I want it to add this to the style sheet...

```
 --precise-red-50
 --precise-red-100
 --precise-red-200
 --precise-red-300
 --precise-red-400
 --precise-red
 --precise-red-600
 --precise-red-700
 --precise-red-800
 --precise-red-900
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why your `@function` not works:** With `@return` you end the function and `@return`'s the result ... so your `@function` will stop on the first step in your loop.

So, if you really want to use a function first write the values to a map and return the map to a var.

But note: in SASS a `@function` is not the best choice to write code to css. It is more used to return a single value. If you would need a multiused solution use a `@mixin` (it is to write calculated code to the css file) or if it is a single task in your project a simple `@each` loop does the job as well.

One more thinking:

Only writing var names to css does not even helps without advising a value to it. So maybe you like to do:

```
:root {
   --precise-red-50: #fee9e8;
   --precise-red-100: #fbc8c6;
   ...
}
```

However. We had a very similar question here some days ago. Maybe you like to have a look ... It was about writing css color vars based on lists/maps similar to yours to css file. If with or without advising color to the css vars ... please adapt the code to your needs:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66854088/9268485

---

**Update:** Additional Example

Here is another similar example from the last days. In this case the task was to write the color swatch build on a color direct to css vars. The shades had been calculated in same process:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66850423/9268485

(If you are not confirm with Bootstrap colors and color maps here is a short overview to this example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/color/)

Comment: This is great info, thank you. Yeah, the function code is a bit old. What I was trying to do at one point is use the function to create a list that is returned then looped over. So something like "--precise-red-50: #fee9e8; --precise-red-100: #fbc8c6;" but let me see if a mixin would work better.

Comment: So have a look to the second (updated) example. Based on a simple basic color value it calculates the color shades/tints for the color swatch and names and writes the css variables for every color to `:root`. As I don't know how experienced you are in Bootstrap have a look to the used Bootstrap map '$theme-color' so it is easier to understand. The map structure is similar to yours: `aNameForTheColor: #hexColorValue`.